# As I know in range queries, Cassandra retrieves result ordered by culstring key. Can I change this behavior in my query?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm trying to store and retrieve last active sensors by this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE last_signals (
  section bigint,
  sensor  bigint,
  time    bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY (section, sensor)
);
```

Row of this table will be updated every few seconds and in the result hot sensors will remain in `memtable`. But what will happen when I get a run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM last_signals 
   WHERE section = ? AND time > ?
   Limit ? 
   ALLOW FILTERING;
```

And the result will be something like this (Ordered by clustering key):

```
 sect | sens | time 
------+------+------
    1 |    1 |    4 
    1 |    2 |    3 
    1 |    4 |    2 
    1 |    5 |    9
```

The first Question: Is this result guaranteed to be the same in all version? (I'm using 3.7) and the next one is that how I can change this behavior (with query option, modeling or etc.). Indeed I need to get last writes first without considering clustring-keys order. I think in this case my reads will be much faster.

Comment: Cassandra is not very good at updates, each update leaves a tombstone until next compaction, and if there are many of them read performance may be impacted as it will have to scan through them. You will probably need to consider schema change, but first can you tell how many sections and sensors at most will you have?

Comment: @yurgis Yes your'e right, but I've considered that and I will use layerd compaction as my storage-engine; plus that I'll configure my memtable size to be able to keep all hot sensors in memtable, and then in this case updates will not have huge cost on compaction. I'll have hundreds sensors per section and millions of sections; but I'll have about ten hot sensors per section that needs updates in every minute.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to guarantee order besides using clustering keys. Thus your ALLOW FILTERING query is potentially costly and may even time out. You could consider the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE last_signals_by_time (
  section bigint,
  sensor  bigint,
  time    bigint,
  dummy   bool,
  PRIMARY KEY ((section, sensor), time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);
```

Instead of updates do inserts with TTL so that you do not have to clean up old entries manually. (The dummy field is needed in order for TTL to work)

And then just run your read queries per section/sensors in **parallel**:

```
 SELECT * FROM last_signals_by_time 
   WHERE section = ? AND sensor = ?
   LIMIT 1;
```